# Query to Id referencing to an 'Id' to the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

I have a table `AMZ_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS` with `Employee Id`, `Employee Name` and `Supervisor1` and `Supervisor 2`. The Supervisors are employee itself but represented by their name.
My task was to replace the Supervisor names with their Ids.

[image]

I have used the following query to obtain the solution but it uses sub-queries and the query does look optimized. For this I have also made a dimension table with all the `Id` and `Employee Names` ,table `AMZ_EMPLOYEE`

```
SELECT S1.ID, S1.EMP_NAME, S1.SUPER_1_NEW, ZZ.ID AS SUPER_2_NEW
FROM 
(SELECT A.ID,A.EMP_NAME,A.SUPER_1,A.SUPER_2,Z.ID AS SUPER_1_NEW 
FROM AMZ_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS A
LEFT JOIN 
AMZ_EMPLOYEE Z
ON A.SUPER_1 = Z.EMP_NAME ) S1
LEFT JOIN 
AMZ_EMPLOYEE ZZ
ON S1.SUPER_2 = ZZ.EMP_NAME 
ORDER BY 1
```

The following is the expected output.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic to use two self-`LEFT JOIN` is correct. You don't need to use subqueries though. Consider:

```
SELECT a.id, a.emp_name, a1.id, a2.id
FROM amz_employee_details a
LEFT JOIN amz_employee a1 ON a1.emp_name = a.super_1
LEFT JOIN amz_employee a2 ON a2.emp_name = a.super_2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! This is what I wanted.